# Change Team Foundation Server 2018 Website Settings

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2018 in a machine.
In the installation wizard I had some options regarding the "Web Site Settings".

[image]

After the installation how can I change those settings? I need to change the Site Bindings.
Can you tell me how to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change site bindings after your installation, you should start up your IIS-manager on the machine you have installed it on.
Team Foundation Server 2018 has created a site on that, so you can change your site bindings on the site.